# Не адаптируется отображение email письма в мобильном браузере

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email, адаптивная-верстка

Есть сверстанное через foundation for emails письмо, при проверке в браузере все хорошо адаптируется, в мобильных приложениях почты тоже все замечательно, но если открыть письмо в мобильном браузере то оно отображается в оригинальном размере.

Upd: как выяснилось веб интерфейс gmail не поддерживает медиазапросы, убрал все стили с медиазапросами и немного поправил инлайновые стили, при проверке адаптивности в браузере в ок, а в письме на мобильном проблема остается.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" class="newsletter" style="background: #fff !important;">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body style="-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; Margin: 0; background: #fff !important; box-sizing: border-box; color: #444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; min-width: 100%; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100% !important;">
  <span class="preheader" style="color: #f3f3f3; display: none !important; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; mso-hide: all !important; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus enim corporis provident, ipsam impedit, temporibus consequatur nisi veniam doloribus laudantium.</span>
  <table class="body" style="Margin: 0; background: #fff !important; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; height: 100%; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
    <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
        <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
          <table align="center" class="container float-center" style="Margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; float: none; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; max-width: 600px; width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="logo small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 32px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; padding-top: 58px; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
                                  <img src="" alt="logo" width="160" height="37" align="center" class="float-center" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; Margin: 0 auto; clear: both; display: block; float: none; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: auto; background-color: lightgray;">
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="wide small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 24px; padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
                                  <a href="#" align="center" class="float-center" style="Margin: 0; color: #2199e8; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="" alt="img" width="600" height="400" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto; height: auto; background-color: beige;">
                                  </a>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="text small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <h2 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: inherit; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                                <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #707070; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, mollitia totam reiciendis alias tempore! Voluptate, eos, est! Id quam non tempora, est, consequuntur temporibus iure quia, numquam eius cum adipisci.
                                </p>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="button-wrap small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
                                  <table class="button float-center" style="Margin: 0 0 16px 0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; float: none; margin: 0 0 16px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: auto;">
                                    <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                      <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
                                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                                          <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                            <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; background: #2199e8; background-color: #454fff; border: none; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-radius: 30px; color: #fefefe; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="#" style="Margin: 0; border: 0 solid #2199e8; border-radius: 3px; color: #fefefe; display: table-cell; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 15px 30px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                            Подробнее
                        </a></td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="wide small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 24px; padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
                                  <a href="#" align="center" class="float-center" style="Margin: 0; color: #2199e8; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="" alt="img" width="600" height="400" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto; height: auto; background-color: beige;">
                                  </a>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="button-wrap small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
                                  <table class="button float-center" style="Margin: 0 0 16px 0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; float: none; margin: 0 0 16px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: auto;">
                                    <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                      <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
                                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                                          <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                            <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; background: #2199e8; background-color: #454fff; border: none; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-radius: 30px; color: #fefefe; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="#" style="Margin: 0; border: 0 solid #2199e8; border-radius: 3px; color: #fefefe; display: table-cell; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 15px 30px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                            Подробнее
                        </a></td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="footer small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 45px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; max-width: 544px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                              <th style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                                <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #a1a1a1; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                                  © Lorem 2018<br> Вы получили это письмо на {{customer.email}}, потому что зарегистрировались<br> в Lorem и интересуетесь автоматизацией интернет-магазина.
                                </p>
                                <unsubscribe>
                                  Отписаться в 1 клик
                                </unsubscribe>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander" style="Margin: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: center; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- prevent Gmail on iOS font size manipulation -->
  <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Может вы задаете размеры не через `px` а `auto` ?

Comment: Где код вашего письма?

Comment: @newProgrammer auto используется только для изображений

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko добавил